# How to use passport.js and OpenID Connect strategy with Azure AD

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I looking to authenticate users using OpenID Connect, Node.js, Passport.js against Azure AD. Could you please point me to any resources/docs and/or sample code?

I came across [passport-openidconnect](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openidconnect). Is this still the active module? are you aware of any other module that I could use for this? If so if you could point me to some sample code that would be great!

Comment: Hi, have you solved your issue now? If you have any update, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a passport module specifically for Azure AD called *passport-azure-ad*

The steps to do set this up are:

1. Register your application (in Azure AD)
2. Install all the required npm packages.
3. Setup your app to use the passport-azure-ad.

   3.a Setup the passport strategy

   3.b Add methods to keep track of logged in users

   3.c Initialize passport while loading the express engine

   3.d Add the routes that will handle login/logoff
4. Use passport to issue sign-in and sign-out requests to Azure AD

Check out the official docs (which include a sample) for code for each of these steps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is positive. There are several node.js modules you can use to implement authentication via AAD.

- You can use the ADAL for node.js library, which makes it easy for node.js applications to authenticate to AAD in order to access AAD protected web resources. Please refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs for details and code samples.
- You can use third-party module such as `passport-azure-ad`, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect for the sample which implement the requirement leveraging `express` and `passport-azure-ad`.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.